# If two devices are 180m apart, can they be connected using just one router in the middle?

Tags: router, ethernet, ip-camera, signal-strength

I understand that the maximum safe distance for a CAT6 ethernet cable to stream data is 90m (between source and destination).

I have one router. I want to get a stream from my IP camera, which is 180m away from my computer. The camera has its own power supply, so it doesn't need PoE.

I have a router placed right on top of my computer, but I am planning to place it right in the middle (i.e 90m away from the computer, in the direction of the camera) because the router has no other job.

[image]

So is it possible? Using no external switch. Or do I need to buy a special type of router for that? Or also put a switch in the middle also?

Comment: in your diagram, are both cables connected to the LAN switch on the router, or do you want them to be seperate networks (so one cable is connected to the router WAN port, and the other connected to a LAN port)?

Comment: I don't understand why you would use a $50 router rather than a $20 switch

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that the maximum safe distance for a CAT6 ethernet cable to stream data is 90m (between source and destination).

That depends on the link mode (transmission speed). You're most likely using Gigabit Ethernet, which is usually listed as having a maximum is 100 meters. However, this is 1) specified for Cat5, not for Cat6; and 2) is not a strict maximum, but more of a "certified Cat5 cable is expected to work for up to 100 meters" maximum.

So a good quality Cat5 cable can still work well beyond 100m, and I assume that a Cat5e or even Cat6 should work *far* beyond 100m (although I still wouldn't try to stretch it to 180 meters). I've heard "100–150m" being quoted as a practical distance.

But either way, in your diagram **you have two separate 90m Ethernet links** ("computer-router" and "router-camera"), so the 180m total is not relevant at all. This applies equally whether they're separate router interfaces or whether they're switched ports; even a switch still terminates the Ethernet link.

(Modern switched Ethernet does not have "collisions", so the original source of the 100m maximum distance related to collision detection is no longer relevant. Shared-medium Ethernet connected using hubs was a different world.)

> Using no external switch

There is literally no difference between an external switch and your router's built-in switch: both are the same kind of Ethernet switch. (Though a dedicated switch would likely be *more* suitable than a router, just because it's smaller and because you aren't using any "router" functionality in your plan.)

---

Alternatives:

- Fiber optic, using a pre-made 200m SMF cable between two fiber-to-ethernet "media converters".
- Mikrotik's "GPeR" (Gigabit Passive Ethernet Repeater) thing, which is a tiny PoE-powered coupler that can allegedly extend reach by an additional ~200m.